# jQueryMobile: Links in responsive SVG file don't work

Tags: jquery, svg, mobile, hyperlink, responsive

I've created a responsive SVG file that contains 4 rectangle areas as clickable links.  The links work when I open the SVG file itself in a browser.  However, when the image is called in my jQuery Mobile code (see below) they don't work.  I need help figuring out why this is.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Dave

```
<div data-role="page" id="cover"> 
    <!-- Page header -->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" >
            <h1 id=appTitle>Short Game Guide</h1>
        </div>
    <!-- Page body -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="mainImage">
                    <img src="images/Homepage-AI0.svg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem.  I decided to embed the SVG file directly into the jQuery Mobile code.  The image links now work.